# Cube won't deploy

Tags: sql-server, ssas, visual-studio, olap, cube

I was able to deploy a large cube (with 2 dimensions and 1 measure) in Analysis services server but only after setting configuration error options for both dimensions and the measure (through the properties dialog box of each one of them) to specify :

1. `KeyNotFound : IgnoreError` &
2. `NullKeyNotAllowed : IgnoreError` &
3. `NullKeyConvertedToUnknown : ReportAndContinue` &
4. `CalculationError : IgnoreError`

My problem is now after setting the right dimension usage options and after adding an admin access, still  when i try  to browse the cube the measure returns no values (adding the dimensions as well to browse changes nothing).
The cube processing task ends succesfully after mentioning the number of measure rows read in the partition, also the table views data explorer for the measure returns the data correctly.
My question is how to make the cube browsing return the measure rows when i execute the sample query provided by VS2019 ?
PS : the measure i defined has the **float** type.

Hints : when i specify for the measure property `KeyNotFound : ReportAndContinue` the processing of cube stops with error message

> saying reached limit number of errors

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE : FULL ERROR WHEN I PROCESS THE CUBE (translated from foreign language)

> Errors in the OLAP storage engine: Attribute key not found during
> processing of: Table: 'dbo_MyFacttable', Column: 'Field7', Value:
> '7811'; Table: 'dbo_MyFacttable', Column: 'Champ14', Value: '3.64000'.
> The attribute is 'Field1'. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The
> record was skipped because the attribute key could not be found.
> Attribute: Field1 of the dimension: Customer Address of the database:
> MyDB, Cube: Mycube, Group of measures: Facts, Partition: Facts,
> Record: 1. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The processing operation
> is is complete because the number of errors that occurred during the
> operation has reached the error limit. Errors in the OLAP storage
> engine: An error occurred while processing the 'Facts' partition of
> the 'Facts' measure group for the 'Mycube' cube from the MyDB
> database.

Comment: So what are the errors you get in cube processing?

Comment: the error is `reached limit number of errors when reading partition of the measures group` it is an error occuring while the measure group rows are being read

Comment: That message says that there were _other_ errors.  Post those.

Comment: pls see my UPDATE, i had to cover name of the database as welle as the name of the cube

Comment: Also when i specify at the dimensions properties, UnknownMember to be Visible (for both dimensions i define) and KeyNotFound : IgnoreError at the measure level of my cube, the error disappears and the cube deploys but then when browsing the cube only the total of the measure value will show independently of any specified dimension

Comment: Are all of the facts rolling up to the UnknownMember?

Comment: no i'm not sure about that

Comment: In any case the best answer is to fix your data so each fact row maps to a dimension row.

Comment: could you develop a bit ?

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/analysis-services/error-messages-process-database-cube

Comment: Thx, but i have already seen that

Comment: How to do to ignore the rows that don't map dimensions with measures ?

Comment: You might want to switch to the (newer, simpler) Tabular Models. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/tabular-models-ssas?view=asallproducts-allversions

Comment: my project is a multi-dimensional model i can't choose to switch to tabular models

Comment: Why can't you choose to switch to a tabular model?

Comment: it's a project constraint that i can't alter i have to look elsewhere as dimensions / measures attributes ...

Comment: @DavidBrowne one last question is the tabular model suitable for cube creation and browsing ? I thought multidim models are more adequate for cubes in AS.

Comment: Tabular models are generally recommended  for new projects.